# Error compiling a Xamarin Forms Application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, proguard

When I check the Enable ProGuard checkbox in the Visual studio project properties in the Android options tab , I get an error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       "java.exe" exited with code 1.

Is there any solution to this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some-time back. These are the few things which you might help you.

> 1. Change your target Version of Java.
> 2. Update ProGuard from the official site. (This worked for me.)
> 3. Make sure it's not a memory problem. If so, Set Java Max Heap Size to 1 Gb or larger.

***Post your full error log, It will be more useful to help you.
There are various factors why you could get this error.***